# Prove $\log_4 6$ is irrational

Tags: logarithms, irrational-numbers

> Prove $\log_{4}6$ is irrational.

I've seen proofs of this which boil down to:
$$4^{m} = 6^{n}$$

But how does this prove that it is irrational?
For example it is possible to have $n$ be:
$$x=\frac{\log 4}{\log 6}$$

Comment: Not if you also want $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: if $4^m = 6^n \; , \; $  how do we express $\log_4 6$ in terms of $m$ and $n \;  \; ? \; $

Comment: Think about the prime factorisation of each side of the equation & recall the uniqueness of prime factorisation.

Comment: Perhaps you have misunderstood the definition of "rational numbers:" $r$ is rational if we can write $r = a/b$ for **integers** $a,b$, so writing $x = \log(4)/\log(6)$ does not show that $x$ is rational.

Answer (score 3):

We will prove by contradiction. Assume $\log_{4}(6)$ is rational, and equal to $\frac{m}{n}$ for integers $m$ and $n$. Then, we have:

$6 = 4^{\frac{m}{n}}$

$6^{n} = 4^{m}$

$2^{n}3^{n} = (2^{m})^{2}$

$2^{n} = 3^{m}$

But this is impossible, as a number cannot simultaneuosly be a power of $2$ and a power of $3$. Thus, $\boxed{\log_{4}(6)\text{ is irrational.}}$

Comment: Your last line of $2^n = 3^m$ should be $2^{2m-n} = 3^{n}$ instead, as stated in redroid's answer. Also, note $1$ is an integer (actually, the only one) which can simultaneously be an integral power of $2$ and an integral power of $3$. However, this requires $n = 0$, but then $\frac{m}{n}$ would be undefined, so this is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It proves it's irrational because for it to be rational would require integers $n,m$ that make the equation you've written true. However, that equation decomposes into:

$$ 2^{2m} = 3^n 2^n $$

or if you like:

$$ 2^{2m-n} = 3^n $$

For this to be true, an integer power of $3$ would have to be equal to some other integer power of $2$. Since prime decompositions are unique, and therefore any power of $3$ (or $2$) cannot be decomposed into any other primes, this is impossible.